# "Undefined" response when submitting contact form without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, contacts

I am building a basic contact form (three fields) for my site. I have the form built in HTML and CSS; all I had to do was build the PHP to make the form responses send to my email. I found a tutorial and built the PHP file (which worked), but wanted the form to submit in the background and not leave the original page. I found an [online tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59) to do that using Ajax, and after some tweaking, I got it mostly to work. The only issue I'm having now is that when I receive the email with the response, the message field is coming back as "undefined."

I have a good grasp on HTML and CSS, but PHP and JS are new to me (just started learning them for this project), so any help on how to fix this issue and possibly correct any wrong code would be a huge help. I've included the form HTML, PHP, and JS below (PHP and JS are both named 'contact.[filetype]'.

HTML

```
<div id="contact_form">
  <form name="contact" action="">
    <div class="field">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="comments">Comments</label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
      <li><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send Message" /></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $comments \n";
$recipient = "alltheladsmedia@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message From Website";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;color:#505050;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('.error').hide();
  $(".button").click(function() {
    // validate and process form here

    $('.error').hide();
    var name = $("input#name").val();
      if (name === "") {
      $("label#name_error").show();
      $("input#name").focus();
      return false;
    }
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      if (email === "") {
      $("label#email_error").show();
      $("input#email").focus();
      return false;
    }
      var message = $("input#message").val();
      if (message === "") {
      $("label#message_error").show();
      $("input#message").focus();
      return false;
    }

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "contact.php",
  data: {name:name,email:email,message:message},
  success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='success'></div>");
    $('#success').html("<h2>Your message was successfully submitted!</h2>")
    .append("<p>We will get back to you within 24-48 hours.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $('#success');
    });
  }
});
return false;
  });
  });
```

Comment: `textarea` in not an `input` element. Try $('textarea#comments').val().

Comment: your field/variables for the message is not consistently named, it is `comments` in some parts and `message` in others.

Comment: When submitting a test form response, I noticed an error doc was in my cPanel hosting. The message is below:

"PHP Notice:  Undefined index: comments in /contact.php on line 4"

Comment: @Daerik thank you so much! That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your markup the field's id is "comments" but you are looking for "message" in your JS and PHP.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I just went in and fixed that error. That fixed the "undefined" error, but now the field is sending as blank without the text I entered on the form.

Answer (score 0):

you have print your mail result

```
 if(@mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader))
    {
      echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
    }else{
      echo "Mail Not Sent";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I added that in, and the message field is now sending as blank instead of containing the info I put in.

Answer (score 0):

Make few changes if you are using jquery 3.

Change this

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  // Validation here
  // Put ajax outside this block
});
```

Edit html form like this code.

Check the dev. tools if the action attribute is added correctly by the php.

```
<form id="contact" name="contact"  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" >
```

And ajax call into this

```
$("#contact").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Now the page won't redirect
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  // Check console if contact is printed after the form is submitted
  // If contact is printed the url is right
  console.log(url);
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: $(this).serialiseArray(), // Found a typo here fixed
     success: function() {
       // Your stuffs
     }
  });
});
```

Don't put the ajax call inside the input field verification.

Let me know if you find any issue so I can fix my code.

Comment: Where would I add the contact.php URL?

Comment: In html js will do the work for you action="/contact.php" (I assume that contact.php is found in the root so I added a "/")

Comment: Where in the JS file do I add the "contact.php" URL? I added it to the HTML, and now it opens the PHP file when I submit instead of running in the background like it used to. And it still sends blank instead of the message typed in.

Comment: I updated my solution. Also update your question with your latest edited code.

Comment: I used that. The process still takes you to the PHP file instead of running in the background and not refreshing the page, and now the name and email fields aren't working either

Comment: The new code won't redirect. Update your question with latest changes.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I reverted back to my original code and used a method from another user, and that fixed it. Thanks